# postfix mail pipe to php script. Can`t mkdir

Tags: postfix-mta

-Ubuntu 14.04 
-SElinux disabled.
-0777 permission
-mail piping working.
-default_privs = bitnami (main.cf)
-bitnami user in admin and sudo groups.

aliases:
bitnami: "|php -q /path/index.php"

index.php:

```
mkdir("testdir", 0777);
mail('mymail@...', ... , ...);
```

And when i send mail to bitnami, he treated by php script.(receive a letter to mymail@... too)
BUT it does not create a directory "testdir".  Why???

For this reason, I can not use PHPExcel.(not permission)

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute path to create directory. Postfix pipe uses root directory 
`/var/spool/postfix` so your folder is probably located in `/var/spool/postfix/testdir`